# how to merge dataframe with multi level columns structure?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]],columns =["one","two","three"])

y = pd.DataFrame([["w","x","y"],["z","a","f"]],columns =["one","two","three"])
```

[image: dataframe1]

[image: dataframe2]

I want to merge these data frame to become one on their index:

[image: merged columns]

how to make columns as multi level columns?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `keys` parameter:

```
df = pd.concat([x, y], keys=['x','y'], axis=1)
print (df)
    x             y          
  one two three one two three
0   a   b     c   w   x     y
1   d   e     f   z   a     f
```